# Meteorjs semantic ui datetimepicker change event

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to use the change event to get the value of datetimepicker
I also tried with `onChange`,`onSelect` but still does not work. Only click event works:

```
Template.Reservations.events({
  "change .datetimepicker": function(evt) {
    console.log($(evt.target).val());
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not get the value of .datetimepicker element directly because semantic ui overwrite the html using jquery. So for getting the value of data you have to use semantic ui datetimepicker events on template render function when you intilize the datatimepicker.

```
Template.Reservations.onRendered(function(){
    $('.datetimepicker').daterangepicker();
    $('.datetimepicker').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      //You can use these save these value on any varible and use when your form submit by user.
      console.log(picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
      console.log(picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    });
});
```